# Cannot use argb color int value in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

When I want to animate the `textColor` of `TextView` in Kotlin:

```
val animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(myTextView, "textColor", 0xFF8363FF, 0xFFC953BE)
```

this error occurs:

```
Error:(124, 43) None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
public open fun <T : Any!> ofInt(target: TextView!, xProperty: Property<TextView!, Int!>!, yProperty: Property<TextView!, Int!>!, path: Path!): ObjectAnimator! defined in android.animation.ObjectAnimator
public open fun <T : Any!> ofInt(target: TextView!, property: Property<TextView!, Int!>!, vararg values: Int): ObjectAnimator! defined in android.animation.ObjectAnimator
public open fun ofInt(target: Any!, propertyName: String!, vararg values: Int): ObjectAnimator! defined in android.animation.ObjectAnimator
public open fun ofInt(target: Any!, xPropertyName: String!, yPropertyName: String!, path: Path!): ObjectAnimator! defined in android.animation.ObjectAnimator
public open fun ofInt(vararg values: Int): ValueAnimator! defined in android.animation.ObjectAnimator
```

Seems that the value `0xFF8363FF` and `0xFFC953BE` cannot be cast to `Int` in Kotlin, however, it's normal in Java:

```
ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(myTextView, "textColor", 0xFF8363FF, 0xFFC953BE);
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`0xFF8363FF` (as well as `0xFFC953BE`) is a `Long`, not an `Int`.

You have to cast them to `Int` explicitly:

```
val animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(myTextView, "textColor", 0xFF8363FF.toInt(), 0xFFC953BE.toInt())
```

---

The point is that the numeric value of `0xFFC953BE` is `4291384254`, so it should be stored in a `Long` variable. But the high bit here is a sign bit, that denotes a negative number: `-3583042` which can be stored in `Int`.

And that's the difference between two languages. In **Kotlin** you should add the `-` sign to denote negative `Int` which is not true in **Java**:

```
// Kotlin
print(-0x80000000)             // >>> -2147483648 (fits into Int)
print(0x80000000)              // >>>  2147483648 (does NOT fit into Int)

// Java
System.out.print(-0x80000000); // >>> -2147483648 (fits into Integer)
System.out.print(0x80000000);  // >>> -2147483648 (fits into Integer)
```

Comment: Could you add a reference to why this is so?

Comment: Yes, this is very curious.